# Cómo consultar registros con número más alto en Oracle 11g?

Tags: sql, oracle-11g

Tengo un problema al filtrar por número máximo en una consulta sql sobre una base de datos Oracle 11g
Os lo explico con un ejemplo para que se entienda bien lo que quiero hacer:

[image: Tabla 'MiTabla' sobre la que se consulta]

De la tabla anterior quiero seleccionar para cada nombre la puntuación más alta, de forma que el resultado de la consulta sea:

[image: Resultado deseado de la query]

La consulta que tengo ahora mismo funcionando es la siguiente:

```
SELECT * FROM MiTabla ORDER BY PUNTUACION DESC;
```

Esa consulta me los ordena por puntuación de mayor a menor pero no consigo hacer que devuelva solamente el mayor para cada caso. He probado con LIMIT 1, ROWNUM<=1 y más cosas, pero no consigo que funcione. Lo de LIMIT 1 parece ser que en Oracle 11g no es compatible.
¿Alguna idea para solucionarlo?
Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Qué debería ocurrir en caso que tengas dos puntuaciones que sean máximas para un mismo nombre? ¿mostrar un sola?, ¿mostrar las dos?

Comment: Quieres que también salga el `ID` (o, potencialmente, otras columnas)? O basta con la respuesta de Zito_MA?

Answer (score 1):

Probablemente, lo que busques sea, agrupar por usuario y de cada grupo, mostrar sólo la máxima puntuación.

```
SELECT nombre, max(puntuacion)
FROM MiTabla
GROUP BY nombre
```